# System.Web.UI.Page won't let me access CurrentUser or User.Identity from a Controller in ASP.Net-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

When I try

```
user = System.Web.UI.Page.CurrentUser
```

or

```
user = System.Web.UI.Page.User.Identity
```

I get an error saying that the method is not defined for System.Web.UI.Page

I am trying to access it within a Controller, does that matter?

I checked that I do not have another class named Page, Why would it say the method is not defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to do it (basically, they are all the same)

```
User.Identity // in the controller
HttpContext.User.Identity // in the controller
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity // anywhere
```

`Page.User` property works when there's a `Page` HTTP handler that's processing the current request. As in an MVC controller, the request has not been handed to a `Page` class, it won't work.

in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Looks like someone else beat me to it.

Found the answer here: [ASP.NET Controller Base Class User.Identity.Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426110/asp-net-controller-base-class-user-identity-name)
`HttpContext.User` seemed to work alright... anyone see anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

CurrentUser doesn't seem to be a property on System.Web.UI.Page. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx)

Your controller should expose a property named User, does that work?  For example:

```
var user = User;
```