# Why does User.Identity.GetUserId<int>() in WebApi Controller return 0 everywhere except in action methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I'm working on a WebApi project with Asp.Net.Identity v2 (with AspNetUser modified to use int IDs). I wanted to do a bit of refactoring by creating a base class for all my web api controllers. In particular, I wanted the `MyBaseController` class to encapsulate the logic of getting the current user id.

Previously, each action method in each controller called `User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()`. it was cumbersome but worked.

Now I decided to encapsulate that call either in the base class's constructor or in its property. However, it doesn't work: The `Identity` object I get is empty (`IsAuthenticated = false, Name = null...`), and `GetUserId<int>()` always returns `0`.

Apparently it is only inside an action method that `Identity` is populated and `GetUserId<int>()` returns a correct result?

Here is basically what I get:

```
public class MyBaseController : ApiController
{
    public int UserId => User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(); // **this always returns 0**
    public MyBaseController() : base() 
    { var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(); // **this is always 0** }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(); // **also 0**
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get() {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetuserId<int>(); // **the only place where it returns userId properly**
       // some code ... 
    }
}
```

Is there a way to grab `User.Identity` other than in an action method to do something with it in a base class?

The project was initially created in VS 2013 with MVC 5 / WEbapi 2, now migrated to VS2015

Comment: maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1045602/1346098

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access `User.Identity` before authorization. See the [APIController life cycle here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/888/aspnet-webapi-message-lifecycle) or on [MSDN](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36476).

The information is not yet available in the constructor or in `Initialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property in the base controller:

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : ApiController
{
    public int UserID
    {
        get { return User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(); }
    }
}

public class MyNormalController : MyBaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var userId = UserID; // put in variable to avoid multiple calls
       // some code ... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PeterB, but what if I want to do smth with it in my base class? e.g. suppose that I want to load some info based on the user id or pass it to some service from within my base class? no way?

Comment: You can for sure if it happens during an Action which makes a call to the base class. Outside of that I'm not sure. The lifespan or availability of the corresponding HttpContext could be short or long, but I just don't know.